# Как дифференцировать частную функцию?

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь  тета 0 и 1. єто просто переменная и все.

как дифференцировать частную функцию? я знаю что в данной картинке представляем тета 0 как переменная, а тета 1 как константу, или наоборот если производную берем от тета 1. ну что делать с символом суммы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И сказано в Книге - "Учебнике дифференциального исчисления" -

*производная от суммы равна сумме производных*

так что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]